# After compiling Linux kernel on a native ARM device, loading module fails

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module

I have a ARM server with a [Cortex-A57 processor](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a57) and 64GB memory. Due to complexity of cross compilation, I want to compile kernel directly on this ARM server.

I use the similar command to compile kernel and modules, like "make && make modules && sudo make modules_install && sudo make install".

After reboot, I got several errors when load module:

```
[   38.845799] 8250_dw: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[   38.846023] uio: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[   38.846182] uio: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[   38.847622] uio: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: The error "disagrees about version of symbol module_layout" means that the module is built NOT for the Linux kernel which is running.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you for your reply. Yeah. I understand. However, I compile the kernel just on the ARM server. Does it mean I have to cross compile the kernel modules on a X86 machine? I do not understand where I am wrong.

Comment: "I do not understand where I am wrong." - You provide a few details, so we don't know where is a problem too. Knowing the result - your server attempts to load modules (`8250_dw`, `uio`) which aren't build for your kernel - try to debug the situation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I mean all kernel modules fail. I just copy part of the error messages. Back to my questions, will it work when I use "make modules" and "make modules_install" to compile the kernel on an ARM server?

Comment: *Normally*, 4 make invocations, which you list in the question post, should work. Why they don't work for you - we could only guess...

Comment: Thank you so much, @Tsyvarev. I will update when I solve this problem. But for now, I may choose to cross compile on a X86 machine.